# How to convert JSON String to a String array?

Tags: java, android

I made a set of data and put into a `JSON` array and convert it to string so that I could store it into my sqlite database. When I take it out, it is a `String` and it has the form of a `JSON` array:

```
String temp = ["0", "1", "2", "3",.....]
```

Is there any easy way for me to make this into a String array, JSON array or I have to use the old fashion method(substring, split.etc)?

Comment: why not just json decode and then loop over JSONArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily turn it back into a `JSONArray` by just constructing a new instance:

```
String jsonString;  //The string data you pulled out of the DB
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

If you need to go further, you could iterate over the array and turn it into a collection:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String();
for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    items.add(array.optString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

It will simply convert your json string (which is identified by **[...]**) into `JSONArray`.